# Make strip_tags replace HTML with entities instead of nothing

Tags: php, regex

I have this line of code:

```
$content = strip_tags($content, '<a><br><b><i>');
```

It works like it should, but I need for users to be able to enter code and for the code to be displayed on the web-page.
For example,

```
<?php
echo 'Hey';
?>
```

displays nothing. I need it to display

```
&lt;?php
echo 'Hey';
?&gt;
```

for example. What function should I use to do this?

EDIT: To clarify, the user sees the PHP code, it just gets replaced with HTML entities so the server doesn't try to run it.

Answer (score 5):

Try:

```
$content = htmlspecialchars(strip_tags($content, '<a><br><b><i>'));
```

Or

```
$content = htmlentities(strip_tags($content, '<a><br><b><i>'), ENT_QUOTES);
```

See [`htmlspecialchars`](http://php.net/htmlspecialchars) and [`htmlentities`](http://php.net/htmlentities).

Comment: Those do the same thing as just strip_tags.

Comment: Why do you say that?  They are not similar to strip_tags.

Comment: They still remove disallowed tags. They don't replace disallowed tags with entities.

Comment: They don't remove any tags, they just replace things like `<` and `>` with `&lt;` and `&gt;` and `"` with `&quot;` but don't replace any tags.